# Please help me Decrypt this

Tags: cipher

Encrypted Text: `ewzdsaqet`

The only clue I've been given is there are no numeric values.

I'm not all that good with this stuff, so could really do with a hand.

More Info: the cipher was self created with concepts from a lot of different cipher algorithms, there is not tool online that will decrypt it

My friend made it in college! Here's what he sent me in full:

Background: When I say just started I don't mean we looked at Ceasers cipher and implemented it, we went threw a lot of the history starting with the enigma code and progressed from there to present day.

Clue #1:

> There are no numeric values

Clue #2:

> This is a word that is in the Oxford English Dictionary

Clue #3:

> ASCII binary

Comment: Probably hopeless without more information, sorry.

Comment: See: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do (though I appreciate that if your goal is to find out the solution to this puzzle rather than to entertain other people here,

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a simple monoalphabetic substituition cipher, and there are tons of classical ciphers that can be used without a key... It's also probably impossible to perform any valuable analysis because the ciphertext is simply too short. This is why I downvoted.

Comment: (oops, hit enter too early) ... then that's answering a question ("how do I make a cipher puzzle fun to solve?") that isn't yours ("what is the answer to this cipher puzzle I don't know how to solve?").

Comment: If it was "created with concepts from a lot of different cipher algorithms" then I reiterate what I said above: probably hopeless without a lot more information. There are just way too many possibilities and way too little information to constrain them.

Comment: Let's consider the Enigma code mentioned by your friend. The folks at Bletchley Park knew the complete design of the Enigma machine. They had a bunch of outrageously smart people. They were working on it full-time, with *winning a war* for motivation. They often had extra information to help them (e.g., particular words that were likely to occur). I think the shortest message they ever managed to decrypt was about 90 letters long.

Comment: I've been given this clue: ascii binary

Comment: "no numeric values" "ASCII binary"

Comment: I can provide you with a few thousand "correct" answers. `wordlist(find(numel(unique(word))==8 && word(1)==word(2) && numel(word) == 9)`. Paste all English words into MATLAB, put the line above in a loop, and you'll get a few thousand results back. Nothing in the question should suggest any of the answers are incorrect...

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted? We should downvote the friend, not the OP.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 Because the question itself is bad. I really hope *"My friend gave me this cipher"* isn't a valid reason to prevent downvotes...

Comment: I made this, you're wrong, I do not need to educate myself, boys over at MIT cracked it. It was possible with the stated information,
so don't say it was impossible or could've been any word, The decrypt was the word: Elephant Which I also received back from several university's over in the US, Not to mention $600 for creativity from one of the university's Feel free to email me for further information

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: And let us remember that, in addition to “a bunch of outrageously smart people,” the folks at Bletchley Park had an array of [36 processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombe) running in parallel for hours at a time (probably 24×7, but it’s been a while since I’ve read any of the books, so I don’t recall for sure).

Answer (score 4):

I think your friend needs to educate himself a little more about code cracking and decryption techniques.  If he does, he will realize that it is *impossible* for someone to "decrypt" a nine-letter message with none of the following:

- what the plaintext might contain
- what type of cipher was used
- potential keyword(s) (if applicable)
- a significant amount of encrypted text

The solution could *literally* be *any* 9-letter word in the English language.

If your friend really wants to give a *legitimate* code-breaking puzzle, have him supply you with several paragraphs of encrypted text, and then you *might* have a chance at breaking it.

Comment: It could also be a series of words <9 letters long with or without spaces.

Comment: there are only $26^9+26^8+26^7+26^6+26^5+26^4+26^3+26^2+26^1$ different Vigenere keys, but each one results in things